# how to check if function is being called?

Tags: javascript

i have a function:

```
function getPricing(ProductID,VariantID)
{
    //alert('VariantID=' + VariantID);
    if(ProductID == undefined || VariantID == undefined)
    {
        return;
    }

    var ChosenSize = "";
    //var ChosenSizeList = document.getElementById('Size');
    var ChosenSizeList = document.getElementById('AddToCartForm_' + ProductID + '_' + VariantID).Size;
    if(ChosenSizeList != undefined)
    {
        ChosenSize = ChosenSizeList.options[ChosenSizeList.selectedIndex].text;
    }

    var ChosenColor = "";
    //var ChosenColorList = document.getElementById('Color');
    var ChosenColorList = document.getElementById('AddToCartForm_' + ProductID + '_' + VariantID).Color
    if(ChosenColorList != undefined)
    {
        ChosenColor = ChosenColorList.options[ChosenColorList.selectedIndex].text;
    }

    var url = "ajaxPricing.aspx?ProductID=" + ProductID + "&VariantID=" + VariantID + "&size=" + escape(ChosenSize) + "&color=" + escape(ChosenColor);

    //alert("Ajax Url=" + url);
    makeHttpRequest(url,undefined,'pricing');
}
```

But how do i check that its being called? I want to display an alert box.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "check that its being called"? And what have you tried?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't simply set the alert box within the function like you're doing with the commented out debugging?

Comment: Well, remove these two slashes, `//`, at the beginning of your code. Your desired `alert` will appear.. EDIT: Hmm..? Someone upvoted this question?

Comment: Uncomment `//alert('VariantID=' + VariantID);` ?

Comment: the data gets passed to another page.

Comment: @Rob W : Sorry i was supposed to write more for this question.. the data gets passed to another page, and thats where i want to display an alert. But you may dismiss this question now. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put some logging inside of it and check your console?

```
console.log("getPricing just got called with", arguments);
```

or if you don't have a browser with a console, you could always use an `alert`

```
alert("getPricing just got called");
```